# How should versioning of debian packages work with git?

Tags: debian, packaging

As I understand it, debian packages should be named NAME_VERSION_ARCHITECTURE.
but when I use git as version control it and I rename the folder, it threats all files as deleted and then new.

Is there a workaround to the NAME_VERSION_ARCHITECTURE name?

Comment: I don't find the question clear. Are you creating a package? Normally you just have a source tree, and create the package from it filling in the version in the package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “name_version_arch” scheme applies to binary packages, not source packages or VCS repositories. You can name your git repository whatever you like, although it’s common practice to name it after the source package name. See for example [one of my source packages](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ddcci-driver-linux).

The git repository shouldn’t contain the top-level directory named after the package; it contains the package directly.